# Flask: Why am I getting a 404 error?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm brushing up on my Flask skills to make a "Jeopardy score keeper" application. What I'm trying to do right now is to take a player's score from a database and display it on the screen. I keep getting a "404 NOT FOUND" error. Here's my code:

JeopardyApp.py

```
@app.route('/layout', methods=['POST'])
def layout():
    db = get_db()
    try:
        cur1 = db.execute('SELECT score FROM {tn} where name="Tyler"'.format(tn="Score"))
        score1 = cur1.fetchone()
    except:
        flash("This person doesn't exist in our database!")
    return render_template('layout.html', score=score1)
```

layout.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>JeopardyApp</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<div class=page>
  <h1>Jeopardy Score Keeper</h1>
  <div class=metanav>
    <p>Currently under construction...</p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Tyler</p>
          <tr><td>{{ score.score }}</td></tr>
  </div>

  {% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
    <div class=flash>{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route you've set for the `layout` function is only reachable via the `POST` method.
By default, your webbrowser uses the `GET` method.

Change your route this way:

```
@app.route('/layout', methods=['GET'])
```

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the same error :(

Comment: This should actually work. What URL are you using to call the `layout` endpoint?

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, but I actually did get this to work. I think my URL or app.route was incorrect. But, I'm good now. Thanks!